# How to make an image static rather than relative to an element in the same row?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/MOmKzO/ is my codepen.

[image]

Notice how the online or offline image moves with the name? Is their anyway to prevent this?

Its `.icon` in the code:

```
.icon {
  margin: 2% 1% 1% 4.5%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;

}
```

The name:

```
#name {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Just float the image to the right. `float: right`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.

Comment: Already tried float: right, i'm using bootstrap 4 and for some reason that isnt working. @Rob, my simple question was just "how to lock a image into place"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

position absolute on the image, and position relative on the container.

```
.columnMain {
  position: relative;
}
#status {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This  just jumbles everything up. Wish this site allows me to copy images from my clip board into comments ;-;

Comment: here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/bobharley/full/LOzLzY/) edited from your codepen

Comment: Thanks so much, and everyone else who commented and used time out of their day to help. This worked, and i will keep this in mind later. So basically you are keeping the rest of the box relative to the image?

Comment: No, the image is positioned absolute relative to it's parent.
If you remove the `position: relative` of the `.columnMain`, the image will be positioned absolute relative to any parent with `position: relative` or if none, to the window.

Comment: Okay so basically its attacked to relative and its put their?